# Values in MySQL table are not getting updated

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here is the javascript code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".two").click(function(){
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "twoupdate.php",
        data : {action_type:"update"},
        success : function(html){
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

I have placed script links at end

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Now twoupdate.php has following code

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['login']){ 
header('Location: index.php'); 
}

function updatepoints() {
mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die ("Cannot connect to database");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *from member WHERE username='" . $_SESSION["username"] . "'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$points = $row["points"];
$points = $points + 2;
mysql_query("UPDATE member set points='" . $points . "' WHERE username='" . $_SESSION["username"] . "'");
}
if($_POST['action_type'] == 'update') {
updatepoints();
}
?>
```

The code for two class is like this

```
<a href="http://m.facebook.com" class="profilelink two"><span><img src="images/point.png"/></span> Facebook(Mobile user)</a>
```

When user clicks on this link his points need to be updated.However, after I click on the link and open it in a new tab.If I refresh my original pageI don't see updated points.
The point value is set at 100. This was the default value that I had set in MySQL table. Why is the table not updating.

Comment: fyi: you could also combine that instead: `points = points + 2` in an update query, and is this a typo? `loclhost`

Comment: Could you `echo $points` to see if you actually get the right info from the database to start with?

Comment: I added echo $points; just above $points = $row["points"]; but nothing seemed to be echoed. The page with link is first page, then after the link is clicked it points to other page which then further redirects to third page. Can that be a problem?

Comment: `$_SESSION["username"]` where did you set this variable value, i cant see, but may be i am wrong

Comment: I set it in login.php

Comment: can you echo this variable as well, may be this also failing your query, as you are using to get the value for `$point` and `$point` exist. so can you echo this one out to be sure. Thanks. The reason i am saying this, As i cant not find mistakes in your PHP code, so i am assuming some things wrong with value for the variable, Thanks

Comment: I echo it on the page where user has to click on the link. It show like hi, echo $_SESSION["username"]; and it shows the username.

Comment: may be i am not looking at it in the correct way, but it seems alright, did you try mysql_error() after the query as you are using it with the connection, try that as well